# Do something after function is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question, I think the answer will be simple, but I can't really find it ...

I have a function that creates content with ajax. After the function is finished I want to do something with the created content. To do that, I need to wait until all content is created, before I can do something with it.

What I prefer is something like this:

```
viewAllAccounts(function() {
   //do something
});
```

or

```
viewAllAccounts().queue(function() {
   // do something
});
```

But offcourse this is **not going to work** :)

I don't want to touch the viewAllAccounts function, because it is used multiple times in my app.

Is there a simple way to do something after a function is finished, not altering the function itself?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: adding a call to another function (that does soemthing) just before the `return ;` is called on `viewAllAccounts` ?

Answer (score 3):

when you invoke ajax calls with jquery, there are a bunch of handlers that fire when the ajax call completes.  You should hook into those.  Take a look-see at

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

particularly the 'success' and 'error' properties.  just define functions for those and they will get called when the request completes.

Answer (score 2):

For if you do not want to waste hundreds of bytes and a bunch of milliseconds on jQuery*:

You can create a second function:

```
function viewAllAccountsWithFinishingFunction(func) {
  viewAllAccounts();
  return func();
}
```

Then call:

```
viewAllAccountsWithFinishingFunction(function() {
  //do something
});
```

---

<sub>* I do like jQuery, but using it for just one out of hundreds of features it has, I don't find it necessary.</sub>

Comment: i am a designer and this looks genious for me.

Answer (score 1):

Check out jQuery deferred objects:

http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/

http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/